# Failed to create install session with 'cmd package install-create -r -t --full -S'

Tags: android-studio

I am getting an error when trying to run any app through Android Studio after upgrade to 3.5.1.

> Installation did not succeed.
>   The application could not be installed.
>   Installation failed due to: 'Failed to create install session with 'cmd package install-create -r -t --full -S 2123967' '

I have found similar posts in StackOverflow, and these error messages seem to provide additional information or recommendation. However, the error message I get does not provide any other information. I have tried all the solutions I can find, but was not successful. Here is what I tried.

- Clean uninstall (deleted all related files/folders) and reinstall of Android Studio
- All apps fail to launch, even a new empty project created with no changes
- Disable Instant Run (Option does not exist any more) / Update drivers / Update SDK / Rebuild the project / Sync with Gradle / Run Invalidate caches/restart
- Launching to physical android device yields same installation error message
- Emulator itself launches and functions without any issues
- For this workstation only, problem started when I upgraded Android Studio, but it was a big jump from prior version as I did not run it in this workstation for months and months

I am open to any suggestions or ways to get any additional information to troubleshoot.

Comment: Android studio sucks. Did you find any solution?